# Not able to initialize variables when running as another user in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, scope

I'm running a shell script which will do some work as different users(the script is shown below). I am able to access the variables declared in script while running as another user. The variables assigned in the scope of user are not initialized.

```
#!/bin/bash
presentdir="$(pwd)"
sudo -H -u user1 bash <<EOF
echo "$presentdir"
#its is printing the value on console
EOF
```

This is working, but I should initialize the variables in the user bash. When i tried this way it is showing empty.

```
sudo -H -u user1 bash <<EOF
presentdir="$(pwd)"
echo "$presentdir"
#its just prints empty line
EOF
```

Am I doing correct or is there anything I'm missing?

EDIT1:

```
pre_dir=$(dirname "$0")
sudo -u user bash <<"EOF"
echo $pre_dir
#its not printing anything
EOF
```

How can I access the variable defined above and inside?

EDIT2: 
I figured it put. Just preserve the current environment by passing -E and export the variable.

```
export pre_dir=$(dirname "$0")
sudo -E -u user bash <<"EOF"
echo $pre_dir
#its prints file directory 
EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansion happens on the original user side, not on the side after sudo.

```
sudo -H -u user1 bash <<EOF
presentdir="$(pwd)"
echo "$presentdir"
EOF
```

Now after expansion it looks like this:

```
sudo -H -u user1 bash <<EOF
presentdir="/home/orinal_user"
echo ""
EOF
```

ie. both expansions `$presentdir` and `$(pwd)` happen on the original user side.

So the order is:

1. First expand all variables in the heredoc `<<EOF ... EOF`
2. Then run `sudo bash`
3. Then `sudo bash` expands variables again (but there's nothing left).

You want:

1. Run sudo bash
2. Then expand variables

You need to decide on which side you want the expansion to happen. Personally, I wouldn't use heredoc for this at all, and use `-c` option, which allows me to control the quoting more explicitly:

```
sudo -H -u user1 bash -c 'presentdir="$(pwd)"; echo "$presentdir"'
```

will print the output of `$(pwd)` run *after* `sudo -u user1`.

Or double quote the variables:

```
sudo -H -u user1 bash <<EOF
presentdir="\"\$(pwd)\""
echo "\"\$presentdir\""
EOF
```

First expansion expands `"\"\$var\""` into `"$var"` then the second expansion on the `sudo bash` side expands `"$var"` to it's literal value.

Or you can put the heredoc delimeter in quotes (`'` or `"` do not matter)

```
sudo -H -u user1 bash <<"EOF"
presentdir="$(pwd)"
echo "$presentdir"
EOF
```

This will make that heredoc not expanded on the original user side (small and useful trick).

Comment: Are you sure about `\"`? Replace `sudo ... bash` with just `cat` to see the resulting string.

Comment: I have quick question `pre_dir=$(dirname "$0") 
sudo -u user1 bash <<"EOF"
echo $pre_dir
#its writing empty 
` How can I access that variable

Comment: @S.Harish Export `pre_dir` or use `EOF` instead of `"EOF"`.

Answer (score 1):

`$variable` and `$(command)` both expand inside here docs before executing the command consuming the here doc.

In your second case, the string passed to `bash` running as `user1` is literally

```
presentdir="working directory before running sudo -H"
echo ""
```

You can escape `$` with `\$` in the here doc to fix your script. You can replace `sudo -H -u user1 bash` with `cat` to print the string which will be passed.